# Can I use await in a for loop which exists in a function block using await?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I have read a lot of question here about using await/async but now I have a different case.
I want to use await in a for-loop which exists in a function with the await keyword and somehow it does not work using await twice:

```
async import(){
   await this.sp.getResults(queryParams)
     .then(data => {

       for(let i=0; i < data["results"].length; i++){
          this.setData(data["results"][i], this.data_to_import[i]); // how can I use await here
      }

    })
    .catch(
      error => console.log(error);
    )
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top >levels of modules.

If there exists answers to my specific question, I am sorry and I would appreciate if you could share the link so that I can look it up.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe like: ...`.then(async function(){ data => { loop(awaitAndSet()); } }).catch()`...

Comment: @Cat Hey Cat, I appreciate your help. I realize that I have to look some things up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you inner function (`data => ...`) does not have the async keyword:

```
async import(){
   await this.sp.getResults(queryParams)
     .then(async data => {

       for(let i=0; i < data["results"].length; i++){
          await this.setData(data["results"][i], this.data_to_import[i]);
       }
    })
    .catch(
      error => console.log(error);
    )
}
```

Either add it or use the awaited result from `getResults`:

```
async import(){
   try {
     const data = await this.sp.getResults(queryParams);

     for(let i=0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
       await this.setData(data.results[i], this.data_to_import[i]);
     }
   } catch(e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will test it!

Comment: Agreed but you edited a bit heavily, you could also add the async keyword".then( async data => {"

Comment: It is working. I have to look async/await up again to understand the concepts. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: If you want to read up on async/await, I found this post helpful: https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/truly-understanding-async-await-491dd580500e

Comment: @Cat Thank you for sharing helpful posts. I will read it and I hope I will have understand async/await fully then!